# Java - "Rotating" Objects in A LinkedList - Is LinkedList.addLast(LinkedList.removeFirst()) Good Or Bad Programming?

Tags: java, linked-list

In my Java application both of the following will compile and run, and produce the desired result.

```
//"Rotate" the list items one place to the left.
myLinkedList.addLast(myLinkedList.removeFirst());
```

And a "rotation" in the opposite direction

```
//"Rotate" the list items one place to the right.
myLinkedList.addFirst(myLinkedList.removeLast());
```

Both "rotations" only require one line of code each, but I'm wondering if this is the right way to go about it? Are there any pitfalls in this approach?

Is there a better, more robust, less error-prone way of doing the same as I have above which would require more than one line of code to achieve, and if so please explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems fine to me. If you had a truly circular buffer which was *full* you could just move the "start/end" index, but I think the linked list approach will work pretty well. In particular it's still O(1).

Comment: This is pretty close to what `ArrayDeque` does.

Comment: Thanks Jon, the "start\end" index is a good idea which I'll look into using. The code I posted is part of the logic behind a sliding-block puzzle I developed in Swing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [`Collections.rotate`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29).

Comment: `Collections.rotate` takes O(N) time.  `removeFirst`/`addLast` is O(1).

Comment: This makes the intent clear, but performance wise its much worse. Accessing the first/last element of a linked list and appending/prepending is possible in constant time, while Collections.rotate needs time linear to the list size. Someone should probably create a feature request for a special case for LinkedList.

Comment: The question doesn't have performance as a requirement. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil, etc. If I was looking to improve performance, there is probably other things that are much more important, like using an array-based structure. So I prefer the better, more robust, less error-prone way of doing the same.

Comment: deciding between O(n) and O(1) algorithms is not premature optimization in my opinion.

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann I still prefer using the library method. The context we are given is revolves around avoiding errors. O(n) for small n, if another at least O(n) step is going to be performed, if the code is not hot, etc. More likely, something else is going to change to make the funky optimisation bad.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it exactly as you have.

```
myLinkedList.addLast(myLinkedList.removeFirst());
```

The only way I can see this being "bad programming" is if the list is shared between threads and your method rotates an element from one end to the other without holding a lock (I am not aware of any concurrent `Queue` implementation that can rotate atomically.)

Comment: Thanks for your input, finnw. Even though I'm not a professional coder I always strive to do things correctly, hence my "good \ bad programming?" query.

Comment: And the m in front of the variable name.

Comment: @Steve Kuo, I suspect that name was made up for the question and is not the real variable name as used in the program