# How can I shift the elements to left and right by k nodes of Linked List in Java without using built in classes and methods?

Tags: java, linked-list

How can I shift the elements to left and right by k nodes of Linked List in Java without using built in classes and methods?
Input:A->B->C->D n=2(Shift to right by 2)
Output:C->D->A->B

```
 public static void shiftListRight(LinkedList linkedList, int n) 
    {
        if(head==null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        int k=1;
        LinkedList tail=head;
        while(tail.getNext()!=null)
        {
            ++k;
            tail=tail.getNext();
        }
        n%=k;
        if(n==0)
            return head;
        int stepsToNewHead= k-n;
        tail.setNext(head);
        List newTail = tail;
        while(stepsToNewHead-- >0)
        {
            newTail.setNext(newTail);
        }
        
        //Implement your code here   

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304129/java-rotating-objects-in-a-linkedlist-is-linkedlist-addlastlinkedlist-rem You just need to implement methods `removeFirst()` and `addLast()`.

Comment: @Abra I don't want to use built in methods.Is there any other way?

Comment: `removeFirst()` and `addLast()` are **not** built in methods. You need to write them. For example, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507299/how-do-you-remove-the-first-node-in-a-linked-list

Comment: Thanks @Abra for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple algorithm, where you have to use three time `for...each` loop with `swap` method. I give you example for an `array` and you can easily transform it to `List`.

```
// offs > 0 - shift to the right
public static void shift(int[] arr, int offs) {
    offs %= arr.length;
    offs = offs < 0 ? arr.length + offs : offs;

    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
    for (int i = 0, j = offs - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
    for (int i = offs, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

**Output:**

```
int[] arr1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
shift(arr1, 3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));  // [7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

System.out.println();

int[] arr2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
shift(arr2, -3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));  // [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks @oleg.cherednik

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample input and output in your question, I would say that you want to **rotate** the elements in your linked list and not *shift* them.

Here is my implementation of the SO question entitled [Java - “Rotating” Objects in A LinkedList - Is LinkedList.addLast(LinkedList.removeFirst()) Good Or Bad Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304129/java-rotating-objects-in-a-linkedlist-is-linkedlist-addlastlinkedlist-rem) In other words the code below shows methods `addFirst()`, `addLast()`, `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()` that are mentioned in that question.

```java
public class LinkdLst {
    private ListNode  head;

    public void addFirst(ListNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
            }
            else {
                node.setNext(head);
                head = node;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addLast(ListNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
            }
            else {
                ListNode previous = head;
                ListNode current = head.getNext();
                while (current != null) {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
                previous.setNext(node);
            }
        }
    }

    public ListNode removeFirst() {
        ListNode removed;
        if (head == null) {
            removed = null;
        }
        else {
            removed = head;
            head = head.getNext();
        }
        return removed;
    }

    public ListNode removeLast() {
        ListNode removed;
        if (head == null) {
            removed = null;
        }
        else {
            ListNode previous = null;
            ListNode current = head;
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            removed = current;
            if (previous != null) {
                previous.setNext(null);
            }
            else {
                head = null;
            }
        }
        return removed;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            sb.append(current);
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkdLst list = new LinkdLst();
        list.addLast(new ListNode('A'));
        list.addLast(new ListNode('B'));
        list.addLast(new ListNode('C'));
        list.addLast(new ListNode('D'));
        System.out.println(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            list.addLast(list.removeFirst());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            list.addFirst(list.removeLast());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

class ListNode {
    private char  data;
    private ListNode  next;

    public ListNode(char datum) {
        data = datum;
    }

    public ListNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(ListNode node) {
        next = node;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%c-> ", data);
    }
}
```

First I create the list according to the sample in your question. Then I rotate them by 2 to get the desired result also according to the sample in your question. Then I rotate the "rotated" list by 2 in the opposite direction which returns the "rotated" list to its original order. Here is the output when running the above code.

Note that the `toString()` methods in the above code are only for debugging purposes and are not part of the implemented solution. In other words, you can safely remove them.

```
A-> B-> C-> D-> 
C-> D-> A-> B-> 
A-> B-> C-> D->
```